# Distribute lines to files based on character of first column (with awk)

Tags: awk

I have a file with tab-separated columns

```
AB01    1234
AB02    2342
CD01    dfde
CD02    3493
CD03    fdja
CDNC01  3343
Hans01  234r
Hans02  3jfe
HansNC01    jeff
```

I need to split this file into multiple files named after a part of the first column entry.
In the new file the whole line should go in to.
E.g. The first two lines should go into a file called `AB.csv` and so on.

This may clarify it:

```
AB01    1234 --> file: AB.csv
AB02    2342 --> file: AB.csv
CD01    dfde --> file: CD.csv
CD02    3493 --> file: CD.csv
CD03    fdja --> file: CD.csv
CDNC01  3343 --> file: CD.csv
Hans01  234r --> file: Hans.csv
Hans02  3jfe --> file: Hans.csv
HansNC01    jeff --> file: Hans.csv
```

It is usually everything until the number (two digits), but also if there is `NC` before the number.

Any help and hint is welcome.

---

**EDIT**

For the sake of completeness and to show my hopeless results:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{ $1 ~ /(.+?)(NC|)\d\d/; \
    printf "%s\n", $0 >> <VARIABLE>".csv"}' \
    file.csv
```

The first problem is getting a match for the first column. The second problem is getting the result as variable for the csv-file.

Comment: Since effort from you is lacking, this looks more like a wish than a question.

Comment: Thank you for adding your efforts in your question, could you please confirm how `HansNC01` line has output file as `Hans.csv`? It should be `HansNC.csv` right? Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: `HansNC01` should also go to `Hans.csv`, `NC` is for negative control so it belongs also to the "Hans-data".

Comment: IMHO, OP has added efforts in question, this could be re-opened now, thank you.

Comment: is input data already sorted by first column? if not already sorted, is there a requirement to maintain the original ordering of the input rows when writing to the target files (eg, if we start by sorting the input file then we could lose the original ordering of rows); how many lines could this file contain? (100's? thousands? millions?)  does the numeric component of the first column **always** consist of 2-digits?  should the solution be case sensitive (eg, should `AB01`, `abNC03` and `AbnC75` be written to the same target file and if 'yes' then what is file name: `AB`, `ab` or `Ab`)?

Comment: This file has up to 200 rows and the first column is sorted in a preprocess. It is also possible to do the sorting on the fly when distributing the lines to the files. At least in the end the lines are sorted by the first column.

There can be 1-3 digits as the last part of the first column. If there is capital `NC` directly before the digits then it is not part of the name. Anything from starting column until `NC` or a digit is part of the (file) name.

Comment: could you have an entry like `NC028` and if so ... write to file `NC` or `???`; also, can the 'first part' of the first column contain numbers (eg, `AB27NC132`)?

Comment: Lines starting e.g. with `NC` followed by a number should be ignored.  "First parts" are ought to only have characters (a-zA-Z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This should help when lines are not sorted by 1st field.

```
awk '
{
  close(first)
  first=$1
  gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]*|NC/,"",first)
  print >> (first".csv")
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation of above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  close(first)                     ##Using close function with variable first value which is an output file name.
  first=$1                         ##Creating first with 1st field value here.
  gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]*|NC/,"",first)   ##Using gsub to substitute everything apart from alphabets OR NC with null in first variable.
  print >> (first".csv")           ##Printing current line into first.csv which is output file.
}
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP comments if data is sorted by 1st field then one could try following.

```
awk '
{
  first=$1
  gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]*|NC/,"",first)
}
prev!=first".csv"{
  close(prev)
}
{
  print > (first".csv")
  prev=first".csv"
}
' Input_file
```